# Assign derived template class to base class template

Tags: c++, templates

This seems not possible, but I think it is reasonable to have what I looking for. I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class Data{
  T getData() {
    return data;
  }
  private:
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
class Base : public Data<T> {
  public:
    void someCommonAction() { }
};

class DerivedInt : public Base<int> {
};

class DerivedFloat : public Base<float> {
};
```

I want to assign derived objects to the `Base` class, but the compiler complains that template argument is required for `Base`:

```
Base b = DerivedInt{};
```

I understand that the `Base` class template itself is not a complete class, but requirements like this is quite reasonable to me. Are there any alternatives to achieve what I want?

Comment: [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (since C++17) would do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> understand that the Base class template itself is not a complete class, but requirements like this is quite reasonable to me. Are there any alternatives to achieve what I want?

Reasonable but you need template argument deduction; so starting from C++17 you can add something as

```
template <typename T>
Base(Base<T>) -> Base<T>;
```

and

```
Base b = DerivedInt{};
```

should work.

Off topic: observe that in

```
template <typename T>
class Data{
  T getData() {
    return data;
  }
  private:
    T data;
};
```

the `getData()` method is **private**

I suppose your intention was make it **public**

template

```
class Data{
  public:
     T getData() {
       return data;
     }
  private:
    T data;
};
```

or make `Data` a `struct`

Comment: Is this achievable only with C++17?

Comment: @neevek - directly `Base b = something;`? Yes, as far I know. Pre C++17 you can create a `make_base()` (following the `std::make_tuple()`, `std::make_pair()` examples) and use `auto`: `auto b = make_base(DerivedInt{});`